# Is there any way to play gpu accelerated video without X?

Tags: console, gpu

You can play use mplayer on fbdev, but not with the gpu. That's as close as I can find.

Comment: I guess technically Wayland isn't X, and there's a mplayer fork for it...

Answer (score 3):

I know that it is possible; `omxplayer` works sans X on the framebuffer using GPU acceleration, although it is intended for one specific device (the [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi)).

However, I believe it accesses the GPU via [OpenMAX](http://www.khronos.org/openmax/) (hence *omx* -player), which is cross-platform.  Meaning, this isn't why `omxplayer` is pi-specific.  Unfortunately, casual searching doesn't reveal anything else that does this (openmax + framebuffer).  You could try bugging the [omxplayer people](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) and see if anyone has ported it to x86(_64).

Comment: Thanks. I can't find any google hits for omxplayer x86. Maybe it will just build.

Comment: Let us know if that works out!